# Database that can handle >500 millions rows

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql

I am looking for a database that could handle (create an index on a column in a reasonable time and provide results for *select queries* in less than 3 sec) more than 500 millions rows. Would Postgresql or Msql on low end machine (Core 2 CPU 6600, 4GB, 64 bit system, Windows VISTA) handle such a large number of rows?

Update: Asking this question, I am looking for information which database I should use on a low end machine in order to provide results to select questions with one or two fields specified in where clause. No joins. I need to create indices -- it can not take ages like on mysql -- to achieve sufficient performance for my select queries. This machine is a test PC to perform an experiment.

The table schema:

```
 create table mapper {
        key VARCHAR(1000),
        attr1 VARCHAR (100),
        attr1 INT,
        attr2 INT,
        value VARCHAR (2000),
        PRIMARY KEY (key),
        INDEX (attr1), 
        INDEX (attr2)   
    }
```

Comment: See my answer below.  Again, it depends on a whole lot of factors including row size, joins, etc.  It is going to be impossible for anyone to give you a definitive answer other than to say "every dbms  can do this.. depending on your data"  Technically speaking, the differences in performance amongst the various dbms are going to come down to the actual data and how you dice it.

Comment: Stating this question, I was looking for information which database I should use on a low end machine in order to provide results to *select* questions with one or two fields specified in *where* clause. No *joins*. I need to create indices (that does not take ages like on mysql) to achieve sufficient performance for my select queries.

Comment: @Skarab: note that the way to have an *exact* answer to your question is to create a database, fill it with 5×10⁸ random records, and test it. Yes, it's longer to do (especially if you need to install the SQL servers), but at least you will be sure to make a right choice.

Comment: give us some example of expected queries and what your table is going to look like.  Also, which OS?

Comment: Your example implies that you are going to do a pivot table.  Is that right?  Or are you just going to do a select and pivot in code?  The answer has a tremendous impact in server performance depending on how wide the resulting table is... And may be covered by moronic MS patents.

Comment: No, in 90% cases I need selects, sometimes I need to sum some values but I would not say that I want to create a pivot table.

Comment: postgresql not very good with large dataset.  may have to do something more exotic like aggregation tables.

Comment: @Skarab you should really accept the answer by ChrisLively if you've forgotten and it helped you.

Comment: Hi All, I've a table with 16 columns in MSSQL database containg 1.5 crore records and I insert  3.25 Lac average no. of rows on daily basis. Before inserting every new single rows, I'm checking with 5 columns values in table. If no row found based on that 5 columns values then can insert new row only. Please suggest me how can I do it in efficient way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

MSSQL can handle that many rows just fine.  The query time is completely dependent on a lot more factors than just simple row count.

For example, it's going to depend on:

1. how many joins those queries do
2. how well your indexes are set up
3. how much ram is in the machine
4. speed and number of processors
5. type and spindle speed of hard drives
6. size of the row/amount of data returned in the query
7. Network interface speed / latency

It's very easy to have a small (less than 10,000 rows) table which would take a couple minutes to execute a query against.  For example, using lots of joins, functions in the where clause, and zero indexes on a Atom processor with 512MB of total ram. ;)

It takes a bit more work to make sure all of your indexes and foreign key relationships are good, that your queries are optimized to eliminate needless function calls and only return the data you actually need.  Also, you'll need fast hardware.

It all boils down to how much money you want to spend, the quality of the dev team, and the size of the data rows you are dealing with.

**UPDATE**
Updating due to changes in the question.

The amount of information here is still not enough to give a real world answer.  You are going to just have to test it and adjust your database design and hardware as necessary.

For example, I could very easily have 1 billion rows in a table on a machine with those specs and run a "select top(1) id from tableA (nolock)" query and get an answer in milliseconds.  By the same token, you can execute a "select * from tablea" query and it take a while because although the query executed quickly, transferring all of that data across the wire takes awhile.

Point is, you have to test.  Which means, setting up the server, creating some of your tables, and populating them.  Then you have to go through performance tuning to get your queries and indexes right. As part of the performance tuning you're going to uncover not only how the queries need to be restructured but also exactly what parts of the machine might need to be replaced (ie: disk, more ram, cpu, etc) based on the lock and wait types.

I'd highly recommend you hire (or contract) one or two DBAs to do this for you.

Comment: This is an extra helpful answer to all my SQL anxieties. I wish I could give more points/favorite answers specifically!:)

Comment: What it says makes perfect sense, so why promote any database vendor over others, especially since MSSQL Server was not in the initial scope ?

Comment: @alci: The initial question specified "Msql". (note the missing second letter which would have defined it) I initially read this as MSsql not MySQL because it was tagged "sql-server"; which is the tag for microsoft's product, hence the call out to microsoft's database server.  In his comments after the fact he actually used the term "mysql".  So, at the time that this answer was posted the actual DB server in use by the OP was not clear.

Answer (score 27):

Most databases can handle this, it's about what you are going to do with this data and how you do it. Lots of RAM will help.

I would start with PostgreSQL, it's for free and has no limits on RAM (unlike SQL Server Express) and no potential problems with licences (too many processors, etc.). But it's also my work :)

Answer (score 12):

Pretty much every non-stupid database can handle a billion rows today easily. 500 million is doable even on 32 bit systems (albeit 64 bit really helps).

The main problem is:

- You need to have enough RAM. How much is enough depends on your queries.
- You need to have a good enough disc subsystem. This pretty much means if you want to do large selects, then a single platter for everything is totally out of the question. Many spindles (or a SSD) are needed to handle the IO load.

Both Postgres as well as Mysql can easily handle 500 million rows. On proper hardware.

Comment: From my own experience, Mysql has often problems with indexing attributes when a table is very long.

Comment: MySQL might get into trouble on it's queryplans, it's pretty limited. But it depends on your type of queries, as usual.

Answer (score 10):

What you want to look at is the **table size limit** the database software imposes.  For example, as of this writing, [MySQL InnoDB has a limit of 64 TB per table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html), while [PostgreSQL has a limit of 32 TB per table](http://www.postgresql.org/about/); neither limits the number of rows per table.  If correctly configured, these database systems should not have trouble handling tens or hundreds of billions of rows (if each row is small enough), let alone 500 million rows.

For best performance handling extremely large amounts of data, you should have sufficient disk space and good disk performance—which can be achieved with disks in an appropriate RAID—and large amounts of memory coupled with a fast processor(s) (ideally server-grade Intel Xeon or AMD Opteron processors).  Needless to say, you'll also need to make sure your database system is configured for optimal performance and that your tables are indexed properly.

Comment: appears that you can increase the PostgreSQL limit manually: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28556/manually-increase-postgresqls-table-size-limit-of-32-tb or also by partitioning [?]

Answer (score 5):

The following article discusses the import and use of a *16 **billion*** row table in Microsoft SQL.
https://www.itprotoday.com/big-data/adventures-big-data-how-import-16-billion-rows-single-table.

From the article:

> Here are some distilled tips from my experience:
>
> The more data you have in a table with a defined clustered index, the
>   slower it becomes to import unsorted records into it. At some point,
>   it becomes too slow to be practical. If you want to export your table
>   to the smallest possible file, make it native format. This works best
>   with tables containing mostly numeric columns because they’re more
>   compactly represented in binary fields than character data. If all
>   your data is alphanumeric, you won’t gain much by exporting it in
>   native format. Not allowing nulls in the numeric fields can further
>   compact the data. If you allow a field to be nullable, the field’s
>   binary representation will contain a 1-byte prefix indicating how many
>   bytes of data will follow. You can’t use BCP for more than
>   2,147,483,647 records because the BCP counter variable is a 4-byte
>   integer. I wasn’t able to find any reference to this on MSDN or the
>   Internet. If your table consists of more than 2,147,483,647 records,
>   you’ll have to export it in chunks or write your own export routine.
>   Defining a clustered index on a prepopulated table takes a lot of disk
>   space. In my test, my log exploded to 10 times the original table size
>   before completion. When importing a large number of records using the
>   BULK INSERT statement, include the BATCHSIZE parameter and specify how
>   many records to commit at a time. If you don’t include this parameter,
>   your entire file is imported as a single transaction, which requires a
>   lot of log space. The fastest way of getting data into a table with a
>   clustered index is to presort the data first. You can then import it
>   using the BULK INSERT statement with the ORDER parameter.

Even that is small compared to the multi-petabyte Nasdaq OMX database, which houses tens of petabytes (thousands of terabytes) and trillions of rows on SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out Cassandra? http://cassandra.apache.org/

Comment: What problem would that solve? Every DB can handle this amount of records.

Comment: "Core 2 CPU 6600, 4GB, 64 bit system, Windows VISTA" not really the type of machine i'd suggest cassandra for...

Comment: @rogerdpack see https://techcrunch.com/2010/09/07/digg-struggles-vp-engineering-door/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned pretty much all DB's today can handle this situation - what you want to concentrate on is your disk i/o subsystem. You need to configure a RAID 0 or RAID 0+1 situation throwing as many spindles to the problem as you can. Also, divide up your Log/Temp/Data logical drives for performance.

For example, let say you have 12 drives - in your RAID controller I'd create 3 RAID 0 partitions of 4 drives each. In Windows (let's say) format each group as a logical drive (G,H,I) - now when configuring SQLServer (let's say) assign the tempdb to G, the Log files to H and the data files to I.

Comment: I've a table with 16 columns in MSSQL database containg 1.5 crore records and I insert 3.25 Lac average no. of rows on daily basis. Before inserting every new single rows, I'm checking with 5 columns values in table. If no row found based on that 5 columns values then can insert new row only. Please suggest me how can I do it in efficient way? Thanks in advance

Comment: For remaining passerbys, do NOT put your data on RAID0 or RAID0+1.
RAID 0 carries with it risk of data loss; if any drive dies, all data is lost. RAID 0+1 does not have the same risk, but is provably higher risk than RAID 1+0.
Consult a real expert. In lieu of that, use multiple RAID1 (mirrored) arrays. SQL Server is smart enough to span IO for large tables against multiple arrays. You get near linear performance improvement with more disks and lower risk of data loss. Additionally, RAID1 arrays are usually recoverable without a RAID controller, should yours fail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much input on which is the best system to use, but perhaps this tip could help you get some of the speed you're looking for.

If you're going to be doing exact matches of long varchar strings, especially ones that are longer than allowed for an index, you can do a sort of pre-calculated hash:

```
CREATE TABLE BigStrings (
   BigStringID int identity(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   Value varchar(6000) NOT NULL,
   Chk AS (CHECKSUM(Value))
);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_BigStrings_Chk ON BigStrings(Chk);

--Load 500 million rows in BigStrings

DECLARE @S varchar(6000);
SET @S = '6000-character-long string here';

-- nasty, slow table scan:
SELECT * FROM BigStrings WHERE Value = @S

-- super fast nonclustered seek followed by very fast clustered index range seek:
SELECT * FROM BigStrings WHERE Value = @S AND Chk = CHECKSUM(@S)
```

This won't help you if you aren't doing exact matches, but in that case you might look into full-text indexing. This will really change the speed of lookups on a 500-million-row table.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to create indices (that does not take ages like on mysql) to achieve sufficient performance for my select queries

I'm not sure what you mean by "creating" indexes.  That's normally a one-time thing.  Now, it's typical when  loading a huge amount of data as you might do, to drop the indexes, load your data, and then add the indexes back, so the data load is very fast.  Then as you make changes to the database, the indexes would be updated, but they don't necessarily need to be created each time your query runs.

That said, databases do have query optimization engines where they will analyze your query and determine the best plan to retrieve the data, and see how to join the tables (not relevant in your scenario), and what indexes are available, obviously you'd want to avoid a full table scan, so performance tuning, and reviewing the query plan is important, as others have already pointed out.

The point above about a checksum looks interesting, and that could even be an index on attr1 in the same table.