# How do I implement dynamically named tables using MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In the world of ASP.net and MVC, Models get turned into nice tables in my DB. This is great; however, I need a slightly different solution for a project that I don't really know how to implement with brute forcing the tables (yuck).

For understanding, consider a person and a history model.

```
public class Person {
   [Required]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string UserName { get; set; }
    :
    :
    :
   public Guid guid;
}

public class History {
   [Required]
   public Guid ID { get; set; }
    :
    History stuff
    :
    :
}
```

The Person(s) fall nicely into a single table with 1 to n Persons.

How do I leverage ASP.net and/or MVC foundation to get the History into 1 table per person (without manually SQL statements for lack of better words)? A good table name example would be like History-GUID. Where I'd append the Persons GUID to 'History-' to select the table for dynamic creation or CRUD access.

Of am I stuck with manually handling things?

Edited:
It may help to know my reasoning because someone may offer a better methodology.

I'm working with 10's of thousands persons with many thousands history per person. I was thinking that performance would be greatly improved by being able to fetch a single table containing the needed history for that one person. Instead of having to work through that many history entries for 1 person from a single history table consisting of all the history entries.

Am I crazy for even worrying about this causing a performance problem?

Comment: Why not just add a `History` GUID property to `Person`?  You then have all `History` data stored in the same table, and you can select a `Person`s `History` based on the value of the `Person.History` property.

Comment: John has a good idea. But I would say you only need a foreign key in your History table: PersonGUID.  Then you could get the history of a person based on his GUID.  I dont' really understand why you need a table for each person.  This does not make sense and it is getting away from the database concept.

Comment: you are referring to a table consisting of all of history data of each person, right? The purpose of splitting them into different tables is performance. 10's of thousands persons with 100's of thousands history per person, I was thinking that performance would be greatly improved by not having to fetch that many history entries from that size of a table. These are the kind of numbers I have to work with

Comment: @codea i'm not looking for a table per person. But a table per history relating to one person

Comment: I understand your concern.  But I would stick with one table for history that contains the history of everyone.  If you have performance issues then later you could create optimizations if required. This would depend on the database engine you are using  (Views, indexes, caching, or code/model refactoring, etc).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779088/database-that-can-handle-500-millions-rows/3779131

Comment: I will keep that into consideration and it is my current implementation. My concern is that it is going on line soon (mid-Jan) and the history comes from a semi realtime data collector producing about 1000 histories per day. So if it is a problem, it will show itself real soon; hence my reviewing a solution before it bites me.

Comment: After reading the Related post from John, it looks like it might not even be a problem. We'll see.