# searching millions of rows better data structure

Tags: mysql

is there a better data structure than mysql that i can explore for searching millions of rows? I have a database with millions of rows of data and sometimes need to allow users to search these integer or  varchar columns

i was thinking making exploring apache lucene?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the structure more than the number of rows.

This thread might be helpful to you: [Database that can handle >500 millions rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779088/database-that-can-handle-500-millions-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Apache lucene is a algorithm that will improve your search. But if your database haven't a good structure it'll has no effect.

Millions of rows isn't that much, you can figure it perfectly with mysql but you'll have to look for some features from mysql to improve your performace. Like FK, Indexes etc.

If you'r looking for database to handle billions rows you'll find on Oracle a good choice,

But if you work with lots of static contents, you can use some NOSQL database as Mongo, or AWS DynamoDB.

AWS RDS provides a good scalable solution for database as well.

I hope can help.