# Are double integers more efficient as database IDs than string codes?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-types

This question is relevant to MySQL databases or tables that exceed 1 million rows.

As each row shall have a unique ID (or code) which is later used to create relationships between several tables, is it more efficient to use a double integer ID such as "**1456156148489418189**" instead of string code such as "**ds156b1dsb4ds8b4sd6b14s864ea**".

Does for example JOIN or even SELECT have an easier time searching for a double integer than for a string in a table of more than million rows? If so is there some correlation such as 40 digit double integer is 50% more efficient as a UID than using 20 character string?

Comment: Why double? usigned int can hold 4 billions records in 4 bytes where double is the double of the space and even so you could still use bigint instead which is just as big as a double. Also do you have proper indexes on the columns you actually using that need a index. There are also things like partitioning and other things that would greatly affect the speed. *Yes a int index is faster than a string index in 90% of the cases.*

Comment: I would use whichever is the easiest to work with. The difference in performance is not likely to be great. All other things being similar, I would use the numeric option because the index entries per IO page would be greater, favoring a 32-bit integer over a 64-bit integer if 32-bit is large engough

Comment: Prix: I want to use a random number, using auto_incremented id in user interface output gives me the chills.

user3351494:yes I think big int should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use auto increment instead of string if your id is just for primary key not for shown in user interface

Comment: thats exactly my point... I like to use a common ID to relate tables while displaying the ID in UI. For that reason the ID shall not be easily guessable. Is that an unsafe practice?

Comment: Try to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779088/database-that-can-handle-500-millions-rows)

Hope this helps you a lot

Comment: shen shen: yeah it had some good pointers. I guess my concern is no way near to occur at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Just use int for your ID and put it on auto-increment :)

Comment: As Shen Shen pointed out, using auto_incremented value in UI output is not a good practice while using different value for UI and table relations tends to get messy. Is this way a bad unsafe habit?

Answer (score 0):

> is it more efficient to use a double integer ID such as "1456156148489418189"

Forget it. You can't fit that value accurately into a double. No more than about 15.9 decimal digits.

You could use a 64-bit integer, but be careful how many digits you expect. Max value is 9223372036854775807.

Comment: what do you mean 15.9 decimal digits? do you mean that double integers are not accurate somehow?

Comment: You need to read about floating point. There's an often cited paper you will find called 'What every computer scientist should know about floating-point'. A double only has 53 bits of precision. This is only enough for 15.9 decimal digits.