# How to store customer specific key value pairs of data linked to a record

Tags: sql, database

We are developing an application where records are inserted to a database to be viewed at a later date, we'd like a generic solution to this so we don't have to rework the `DB` every time we deploy this to a customer.

Records have three types of data:

**Common Data:**
A set of a data items that are common to every record such as record Id, record creation date, and record type.

**Extended Data:**
Some of this data is record type specific So Record Type A would Always have Data Elements `A,B,C` and D While Record Type B would always have Data Elements `E,F,J and K`

**Customer specific Data:**
This is data that the customer wants each record of a particular type to hold, for example if a customer requires that All Records of `type A` have a First Name and a Surname, but Records of `type B` Only have a phone number.

The extended data is unlikely to change often and any changes  will likely involve a code change as well so having a table with Common Data linked to an extended data as a `1 to 1` relationship is what we'd expect to do.

What we are having trouble visualizing is how to store the Customer specific data in such as way that makes sense. My initial impulse was to have a 1 to many relationship to a table with `key/value pairs` in it, but given that we expect upwards of `20,000` records to be inserted into the table a day this would lead to a table that is incredibly slow to search as it will likely have `10-20` entries per record.

A seconds solution is to have table with `N` columns in it where `N` is a number sufficiently large that no customer is likely to need to have that many custom fields. Then having a table that maps customer specific fields to the column for each type of record.

A third solution is to store the fields in a Clob as maybe `JSON or XML`, I'm not sure how you would go about doing this and making them searchable though.

I'm sure this is a problem that has been solved multiple times, and I'd rather not reinvent the wheel let alone create a wheel that turns out to be square.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the best solution is 1 - the 1-to-many table. It's certainly a better idea than 2 or 3.

Comment: Even if that table is going to have 200,000 records inserted into it a day.

Comment: I not not 100% certain, but user data is typically stored in a simple 1-to-many table, then give the many millions of rows you'd probably be looking at see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779088/database-that-can-handle-500-millions-rows

Comment: The databases where I worked on tables with millions of rows, we did switch to BLOBs but that was because it was just a bunch of numbers stored in the columns. But I'd always start with the most easy to understand structure first and index it as best you can for performance second

Comment: Depends on the database you use. SQL Server 2008+ allows sparse columns and [column sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280521.aspx), essentially thousands of mostly empty columns you can use instead of key/value pairs. Internally, they *are* implemented as an XML CLOB, but you don't notice this. There are limitations of course, eg limited indexing and constrain support.

Comment: Indeed - it does depend on the database, there's a relatively interesting article on recent bench marking of Postgres against Mongo DB http://blogs.enterprisedb.com/2014/09/24/postgres-outperforms-mongodb-and-ushers-in-new-developer-reality/